# Using GSON to parse a json datafeed

Tags: java, android, json

i have a simple JSON feed which returns an image path, and a set of coordinations. The "coords" can have an unlimited set of coordinations. In my example below it only has 3 set.

```
{"image":"Some data", "coords": {"0":[0,0], "1":[55,22], "2":[46,65]}}
```

How would i use GSON to parse this? How do I build the class for this?

Thanks

Comment: No problem, just a couple of questions.

Comment: your edit is still invalid JSON. See my answer below. And if you edit to to be valid JSON ... what's the problem you're having? If you don't know how to use GSON, their documentation is rather good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're going to have a hard time with that because it's not valid JSON.

http://jsonlint.com/

If it were valid JSON such as ...

`{"image":"Some data", "coords": {"0":[0,0], "1":[55,22], "2":[46,65]}}`

I believe GSON could parse `coords` to a `map` of `<String, ArrayList<Integer>>` but I'd need to try it to make sure.

Answer (score 1):

Add the `gson-1.7.1.jar` file and write this class to get the required `JSONObject` or `JSONArray` from the url.

```
public class GetJson {

    public JSONArray readJsonArray(String url) {

        String read = null;
        JSONArray mJsonArray = null;
        try {
            HttpClient http = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);
            HttpResponse response = http.execute(post);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            InputStream is = entity.getContent();

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            String str = null;
            while ((str = br.readLine()) != null) {
                builder.append(str);
            }
            is.close();
            read = builder.toString();
            mJsonArray = new JSONArray(read);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return mJsonArray;
    }

    public JSONObject readJsonObject(String url) {
        String read = null;
        JSONObject mJsonObject = null;
        try {
            HttpClient http = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);
            HttpResponse response = http.execute(post);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            InputStream is = entity.getContent();

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            String str = null;
            while ((str = br.readLine()) != null) {
                builder.append(str);
            }
            is.close();
            read = builder.toString();
            mJsonObject = new JSONObject(read);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return mJsonObject;
    }
}
```

ENJOY...

Then to parse the JSON see the these tutorials,

[Tutorial 1](http://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide)

[Tutorial 2](http://p-xr.com/android-tutorial-how-to-parse-read-json-data-into-a-android-listview/)

[Tutorial 3](http://laurentszyster.be/less4j/javadoc/org/less4j/JSON.html)